# Angular service - WHY behavior subject instead of using a variable?

Tags: angular

I fail to understand why is it considered a big no-no to use a service property in the components themselves.

I mean, what is the actual use case for which we need a Behavior subject vs just using the variable, change detection seems to be working as expected when changing the service variable as expected.

For example:

App.Component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public myService: ServiceNameService) {}
}
```

App.Component.html:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of myService.items">{{ item.Name }}</li>

<child-component></child-component>
```

MyService:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ServiceNameService {
  public items = [ { Name: "OLD NAME" }];
}
```

Child.Component.ts:

```
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private myService: ServiceNameService) { }

  onClick() {
    this.myService.items[0].Name = "NEW NAME !";
  }
}
```

The above example shows that changing a variable in the service from one component outputs the change, as expected, in another component. **why** do we need the complicate things with a subject instead ? what am i missing ?

Answer (score 1):

first reason: sometimes inside of a component you want to modify the data for the view. like add a field to each item which represents some checkbox value. with just value in the service, you won't handle updates correctly

second reason: usually a lot of components inside of Angular application are marked as OnPush. these OnPush subtrees of your app won't detect changes correctly with the value from service. but with the helpf of subject you will be able to do `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();`

Comment: as for the first, one can modify the actual data on the service, or if it just for display, custom pipe will solve it. as for the second, `onPush` is not the default behavior, so unless one explicitly chooses to set it, its yields no benefit. but I get your point.